# En arrière de / à l'arrière de / au fond de / derrière

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, prépositions

I'm trying to understand the difference between these things. Do I understand correctly if I say:

1) Le chat est à l'arrière de la maison = The cat is at the back of the house (like opposite to the front)

2) Le chat est au fond de la maison = the cat is *right* at the back (like in the depths of the house)?

3) Le chat est derrière la maison = The cat is behind the house (but doesn't specify particularly)

4) Le chat est en arrière de la maison = The cat is *just* behind the house. I reached that conclusion as I understand that "en arrière de" can mean "in the background of"?

Headache!

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Le chat est à l'arrière de la maison = The cat is at the back of
>   the house (like opposite to the front)

Yes, correct.

> 2) Le chat est au fond de la maison = the cat is right at the back
>   (like in the depths of the house)?

That one I would think it mean the cat is hidden in the basement, or somewhere depth inside the house (like a chimney, etc..), but it's open-ended on the location inside the house.

> 3) Le chat est derrière la maison = The cat is behind the house (but
>   doesn't specify particularly)

Yes, correct.

> 4) Le chat est en arrière de la maison = The cat is just behind the
>   house. I reached that conclusion as I understand that "en arrière de"
>   can mean "in the background of"?

Yes, correct. It mean the same thing as *derrière la maison*. So can be in the backward, etc.. , but somewhere behind the house.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to understand the difference between these things. Do I understand correctly if I say:
>
> 1) Le chat est à l'arrière de la maison = The cat is at the back of the house (like opposite to the front)

yes

> 2) Le chat est au fond de la maison = the cat is right at the back (like in the depths of the house)?

yes, at the very back of the house

> 3) Le chat est derrière la maison = The cat is behind the house (but doesn't specify particularly)

yes, the cat is behind the house somewhere

> 4) Le chat est en arrière de la maison = The cat is just behind the house. I reached that conclusion as I understand that "en arrière de" can mean "in the background of"?

yes, the same as derrière la maison ...  in the background of doesn't really apply here.

:)

Comment: How is this different from previous answer?